# preventing autocomplete on submitting many requests on keyup

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, search, autocomplete

I have the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get,new { id="searchform",@onsubmit="seachformsubmit(event);" }))
        {
            <div class="searchTop">
                <div class="searchField posRelative">
                    <input type="text" name="search" data-resultslimit="12" data-url="@Url.Content("~/Home/_AutoSuggestSearchResult")" placeholder="Search products..." id="txtsearch" onkeyup="onsearchkeyup(this);" />
                    <span id="spsearcherror" class="errormsgsearch" style="display:none">At least 3 characters...</span>
                </div>
                <div class="searchAction blackBtn"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="searchsubmit(event);">View Results</a></div>
                <div class="clearBoth"></div>
            </div>
        }
```

Javascript

```
function onsearchkeyup(sender) {
$("#spsearcherror").hide();
var vle = $(sender).val();
if (vle != "") {
    if (vle.length < 3) {
        $("#spsearcherror").show();
    }
    else {
        InitSearch();
    }
  }
}
function InitSearch() {
var elem = $("#txtsearch");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: elem.data("url"),      
    data: AddFormAntiForgeryToken({ 'keyword': elem.val(), 'recordsLimit': elem.data("resultslimit") }),
    dataType: 'json',   
    beforeSend: function () {
        $(".searchresult.ajaxloader").show();
    },
    success: function (data) {  
        $(".searchresult.ajaxloader").hide();
        $("#ulsearch").html(data.html);
        setTimeout(function () {
            pushBlockCarousel();
            matchHeightfnct();
        }, 300);
    }
  });       
}
```

My problem is that `_AutoSuggestSearchResult` is being fired so many times, i need to find a way to prevent it from firing that much on every keypress

[image]

Any suggestions and help are appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the results are different, then what you could do in the routine is when sending the request, capture what was sent last somewhere, such as a data attribute:

```
elem.data("last-sent", value);
```

And then check this attribute to make sure they are different before making a request.

```
if (elem.data("last-sent") == value) {
   return; //exit due to the same value being the last value
}
```

Some auto complete controls implement a delay of a certain number of characters being entered before starting; that may be another option for you.

Comment: but do you mean by delay? how can I implement that?

Comment: For instance, checking how many characters have been typed and only starting to send the values to the server once you hit that number of characters or more (for instance, start doing the auto-complete on the 3rd or more character typed) is one way.  Another way is that once you are ready to send a response to the server, add a 250 ms delay; if the value has changed then cancel that request and initiate a new one...  that could be a combination of setTimeout and clearTimeout but there could be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following technique, whenever the user stops writing, Javascript will wait for some seconds before triggering the request, just use the code below:

```
let input = document.getElementById('txtsearch');
let timeout = null;

input.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        InitSearch();
    }, 1000);
});
```